# Changing pre_save signal into post_save?Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

This are my models:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
  Total_Purchase = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)


class Stock_Total(models.Model):
    purchases   = models.ForeignKey(Purchase,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=False,related_name='purchasetotal') 
    stockitem   = models.ForeignKey(Stockdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='purchasestock') 
    Total_p     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
```

I have done this in my pre_save signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Purchase)
def user_created1(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
        total = instance.purchasetotal.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Total_p'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
        instance.Total_Purchase = total
```

I want change the pre_save signal into post_save signal..

How do I do that?and what changes I have to make in the function?

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's operated after instance `save` method called you need to call it again in order to save the changes. But you need to use the `update` method instead of `save` in order to prevent `save` recursion.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Purchase)
def user_created1(sender,instance, created=False, *args,**kwargs):
    total = instance.purchasetotal.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Total_p'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    Purchase.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(Total_Purchase=total)
```

Comment: The total value is coming 'None' now

Comment: I've edited the last line, please try with this changes. I hope it will work. If not try to print `total` after it's calculated in order to see if it calculates correctly.

Comment: It means that the calculation wrong, was it working before? I mean did total was counted correctly?

Comment: yes after rebooting my server it works completly fine..Thank you @Sergey Pugach'